# Using a period… the mean way?

Tags: punctuation, periods, sentence-ends

Should you put a period after one-word "sentences?" For example, my boss frequently emails me this way:

> Name.
>
> Content content content.
>
> Thanks.

It feels very angry, rude, and standoffish to me and I feel a bit as though it's backed with a dismissive/sarcastic undertone. As if she's not TRULY thankful for my help but rather following some societal requirement for her to at least appear to be grateful.

In other words, I really don't like it. Thoughts?

Comment: Is she a foreigner? This isn't an answer, but using a period that way indeed strikes me as somewhat rude, because to an English speaker that would be pronounced in a way that seems short or impatient. However, I think it's clear that the intention isn't to be angry or short ... there would be better and more natural ways to express that sentiment. People misreading tone in text is one of the oldest issues with that type of communication.

Comment: I don’t think “Thanks.” at the end is particularly rude (assuming he also has a closing salutation and/or signature after it), but it is far more common in English to use a comma after an opening line (and also to include something like ‘dear’ or ‘hello/hi’, depending on how familiar terms you’re on and the formality of the e-mail), rather a full stop.

Comment: It might help if we understood how you would expect it to be written. Are we supposed to take your example literally  or figuratively? I haven't got a clue what you're asking, really.

Comment: Does she use Christian name or surname? Of course if it runs 'Rachel, You are doing a superlative job , Thanks', I wouldn't see much wrong with that. The elephant in the room is what is contained in 'content, content, content'.

Comment: Thank you for the responses - and for the reminder reality check about inferring tone, Jeremy!

Comment: Oops - first time user - added comment too soon. To answer, she is not a foreigner. I often see her use other punctuation marks with team members and throughout the day (seemingly dependent upon mood). No salutation or signature follows. If there is a "hi" or "hello" it has a period, as well. (E.g., "Hi.") I would like to see communication be less abrupt/more inclusionary. It feels like more of a lecture or diatribe than a conversation when it ends so abruptly. So something more like "Hello Name, blah blah blah. Thanks, Name." If it were filled with complements, I wouldn't mind as much. ;)

Comment: With regards to what is contained in "content content content" it could be absolutely anything. Any topic related to work - requests, instruction, clarification, anything. I know the tendency here would be to say "ah, then it's just her tone and you should stop inferring meaning and deal." However, it's not consistent and not as prevalent in communications with others. :P

Comment: That would drive me nuts, so you are not alone.  It looks rude and would annoy me every time I got an email.

Comment: AMEN, Julia! To be frank, each time I see a period at the end of these one word sentences, it feels like it's actually saying "Thanks[f-you]" - It annoys me to no end.

Answer (score 2):

There was an excellent take on this in [TNR](http://www.newrepublic.com/article/115726/period-our-simplest-punctuation-mark-has-become-sign-anger)  last month, and it's worth a read. I gather it's generational -- as an older gent I find it really odd that anyone would perceive rudeness in a period, but it seems I'm out of the mainstream.